# RMarkdown make elements of a list available in the environment

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an RMarkdown document with several parameters.

```
title: "Numbers"
  output: html_document
  params:
     start: ""
     end: ""
     colour: ""
     data: ""
     username: ""
     path: "" 
     ...
```

I need to type `params$start` to access the value of the first parameter within the document.
I use the parameters a lot within my code, which makes doing `params$start` difficult to read. 
I get around the problem by assigning each element to a separate variable, which I can access by name.

```
start <- params$start
end <- params$end
```

etc.

This is long and annoying, since I need to modify it each time I change (eg) the name of the parameter.
Is there a way I can do this automatically within a loop or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the elements of list `params` in th global environment (usually a bad idea, but you asked for it):

````
---
title: "Numbers"
output: html_document
params:
  start: 1
  end: 2
  colour: "red"
  data: "xy"
  username: "cv"
  path: "cv" 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

The params defined are `` `r paste(names(params), params, sep = ":")` ``.

You can also assign them via `list2env`:
```{r, results='hide'}
list2env(params, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now you can use them directly like: 
```{r}
list(colour, data, username)
```
````

Comment: Is it still a bad idea when the environment is contained within the markdown document?

Comment: `assign` and friends (like `list2env`) are made for their side effects. In your very case there is suddenly a variable `utils::data` in the environment, which masks function `data`. Thus, if you (or heaven forbid - somebody else) innocently tries to use `data` in your doc, it will fail with a rather cryptic message. You have to be  aware of these things whenever you tamper with the environment. In any case it is valid code, but should be taken with care / proper documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does doing `data <- params$data` have the same effect? (My real params have far more specific names, which will hopefully not conflict with functions).

Comment: Yes it does. It is not that you must not use this function (it is there for a reason), but that you should be aware of the caveats. Not a problem now, but if you let the code sit for a while and revisit, you may overlook this side effects and you may lose time in finding this bug. So make sure your properly document your side effects and you can go for this solution.